# debugging doesn`t return anything on Warning: Illegal string offset 'panels_info'

Tags: php, wordpress

I need a solution on how to proceed in fixing this Wordpress error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use string offset as an array

code sample line 586:

```
foreach( $panels_data[ 'widgets' ] as $i => $widget ) {
        $widget['panels_info']['widget_index'] = $i;
        $row_index = intval( $widget['panels_info']['grid'] );
        $cell_index = intval( $widget['panels_info']['cell'] );
        $layout_data[ $row_index ]['cells'][ $cell_index ]['widgets'][] = $widget;
    }

    return $layout_data;
}
```

Comment: See this post
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-fatal-error-uncaught-error-cannot-use-string-offset-as-an-array-2/ Maybe it's because of your php version?

Comment: One of those arrays is not declared right, its hard to say without the rest of the code.

Comment: It means `$widget` is a string, not an array.